# How send JsonNode in request body

Tags: json, jackson, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to post some json data to my server w/ retrofit and jackson

```
public interface FooService {
   @POST("/foo")
   Call<JsonNode> foo(@Body JsonNode body);
}

FooService service = retrofit.create(FooService.class);

JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory = new JsonNodeFactory(false);
ObjectNode json = nodeFactory.objectNode();
json.put("foo", "foo");

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
   .baseUrl(baseUrl)
   .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
   .build();

Response<JsonNode> response = service.foo(json).execute();
```

But when I do that the jackson serialization does not seem to be working correctly.  I.E. when I print out the request body on the server side for this request it does not have a foo parameter.

Is this how I would serialize a plain old JsonNode jackson object?

**EDIT:**

It looks like it is trying to serialize the JsonNode object it self instead of calling into its serialize method.  Can I create a ObjectMapper/SimpleModule to tell jackson to call ObjectNodes serialize method, since that extends JsonSerializable.